# How to read a 10x10 confusion matrix

Tags: weka, confusion-matrix

I'm having trouble reading/interpreting a 10x10 confusion matrix and would love some help/feedback.

The matrix is below:

```
a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k   <-- classified as
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 |    a = 0
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 |    b = 1
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 |    c = 2
0    0    0    1    5   11    8    4    1    0    0 |    d = 3
0    0    0    4   39   99   67    6    1    0    0 |    e = 4
0    0    0    4   66 1384  609   65   10    0    0 |    f = 5
0    0    0    8   46  645 1759  344   34    0    0 |    g = 6
0    0    0    1   11   75  412  544   36    0    0 |    h = 7
0    0    0    0    0    9   59   62   63    0    0 |    i = 8
0    0    0    0    0    0    1    4    0    0    0 |    j = 9
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 |    k = 10
```

I understand that correct classifications are diagonal and incorrect classifications are off-diagonal but I'm trying to make sense of what that means.

For example for `f=5`, was it correctly classified `1384` times and incorrectly classified as `g` `645` times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow `<-- classified as` in your output suggests that predictions are in columns, actual classes in rows. (That would fit the Wikipedia [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).) To put a finer point on it, `f` was correctly predicted `1384` times and incorrectly labelled `g` `609` times.

There's a simple way to verify this: Take the sum across rows and columns. Whichever matches the actual count of that character in your dataset is the dimension that denotes the actual, true character; the other denotes the predicted character.